# Calculate a cost for every 15-minute chunk of time elapsed so far

Tags: java, java-time

I want the user to be able to get updates on the cost for the time elapsed for the use of an app. Every 15-minute chunk of time elapsed so far is priced at 10 units of currency.

I care only about elapsed time. Aligning with the quarters of the hour (minutes 0-15, 15-30, 30-45, 45-0) is *not* a goal.

For example, at the beginning, the cost is 0 units. Five minutes later, still 0 units. After 17 minutes, 20 units is the current cost ( 10 units of currency * a single 15-minute block of time completed). After 33 minutes, 20 units is the current cost, as 2 chunks of 15-minutes each have elapsed so far.

The last current chunk of time under 15-minutes is ignored. No [*pro rata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_rata).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration                       // Represent a span-of-time not attached to the timeline. Internally, this class stores a number of whole seconds plus a fractional second as a count of nanoseconds.
.between(                      // Calculate elapsed time. 
    start ,                    // Starting moment captured a while ago using `Instant.now()` call.
    Instant.now()              // Capture the current moment.
)                              // Returns a `Duration` object.
.dividedBy(                    // Get whole number (ignoring remainder) of number of 15-minute chunks occurred within that previous `Duration`. 
    Duration.ofMinutes( 15 )   // Another `Duration` object, our 15-minute chunk definition.
)                              // Returns a `long`, a 64-bit integer.
*                              // Multiply our number of chunks of 15-minutes by the price-per-chunk.
price
```

## Details

Use only classes from the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) packages, defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Avoid terrible legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`).

Capture the starting moment. Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class, to represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), with a resolution as fine as [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
```

Write a method to calculate your cost for elapsed time. In this method:

- First we get elapsed time, the amount of time from the starting moment to the current moment. We do this in UTC, as there is no benefit to involving a time zone. We represent elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).
- Second, we count completed chunks of elapsed time. We define the chunk of time for which we are charging, 15 minutes, using the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class again. Then we call [`Duration::dividedBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#dividedBy(java.time.Duration)) to get a count of completed chunks.
- Third, we calculate cost by multiplying the unit price times the whole number of chunks of time elapsed. If you are using a fractional number for currency, such as US or Canadian dollars,  rather than an integer number, use `BigDecimal` rather than `Integer`. Search Stack Overflow for more info, as this has been covered many times already.

Note the use of [`Math.toIntExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)) to truncate from a 64-bit long to a 32-bit int but throwing an exception if overflow occurs.

Code.

```
public Integer calculateCostForElapsedTimeSoFar ( final Instant start , final Integer price )
{
    // Determine elapsed time.
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , now );

    // See how many chunks of 15 minutes have occurred.
    Duration chunk = Duration.ofMinutes( 15 ); // Charge for every chunk of time in chunks of 15 minutes. You could make this a constant instead of a local variable.
    int chunks = Math.toIntExact( elapsed.dividedBy( chunk ) );   // Returns number of whole times a specified Duration occurs within this Duration.

    // Calculate charges.
    Integer cost = ( price * chunks );
    return cost;
}
```

Example usage.

```
final Instant start = Instant.now().minus( Duration.ofMinutes( 21 ) );
final Integer price = 10;   // This may come from some other place, such as a look-up in a database.
Integer cost = this.calculateCostForElapsedTimeSoFar( start , price );
System.out.println( "cost: " + cost );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/CS6Dui).

> cost: 10

If you want to automatically update the display of the current cost, without the user performing an action such as clicking a button, learn about the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) built into Java. Specifically, see the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).  And learn about how to asynchronously updating the widgets within your particular user-interface framework ([Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin), [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), etc.). Again, search Stack Overflow for more info, as both of these topics have been covered many times already.

If you are concerned about the clock on your host computer being reset, see an alternative [approach by user2023577](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424755/642706).